# Reading file into linked list C++ with node structure in a class

Tags: c++, pointers, object, linked-list, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to read a text file containing the letters "farming" into a linked list of nodes. I've made a class named NumberList that has the structure for the nodes. Here's the header.

```
#ifndef NUMBERLIST
#define NUMBERLIST
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class NumberList
{
protected:
//declare a class for the list node
//constructor to initialize nodes of list
struct ListNode
{
    char value;
    ListNode *next;

    // Constructor 
    ListNode(char value1, ListNode *next1 = NULL)
    {
        value = value1;
        next = next1;
    }
};

ListNode *head;  //pointer to head of the list

public:
NumberList() { head = NULL; }  //constructor 
~NumberList();      //destructor
void displayList() const;  //print out list
void reverse();

};
#endif
```

Where I'm running into a problem is trying to read the text file into a linked list in main().

Here's what I have in main:

```
#include "Numberlist.h"
#include "ReliableNumberList.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

ListNode *letterList = nullptr;  //create a linked list
char letter;
                    //This is where I read the file into the list
//open the file
ifstream letterFile("linkedText.txt");
if (!letterFile)
{
    cout << "Error in opening the file of letters.";
    exit(1);
}
//read the file into a linked list
while (letterFile >> letter)
{
    //create a node to hold this letter
    letterList = new ListNode(letter, letterList);
    //missing a move to the next node?
}
return 0;
}
```

This read file sample came from my text book but the structure its reading into was not located in a separate class. For the life of me I cannot figure out how I reference ListNode struct in the NumberList class. Visual Studio is stating that ListNode and letterList are undefined. I know its because I'm not referencing them properly from the NumberList class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: `ListNode` struct seems to be `protected` from the outside world. The idea was probably so that `NumberList` would have a method (let's call it `push_back(...)`) to add `char`s into the internal (protected/private) list. This way `NumberList` object would manage creation and destruction of nodes, and in `main()` you will need to write only pretty `list.push_back(letter)`, instead  of bothering with creating `ListNode`s directly every time.

Comment: In addition `ListNode` is actually `NumberList::ListNode`. `ListNode` is inside `NumberList`. `NumberList` doesn't have to fully qualify because it IS `NumberList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution to your problem could be this:

```
//------------------------------NumberList.hpp-----------------------------

#ifndef NUMBERLIST_HPP
#define NUMBERLIST_HPP
#include <iostream>

class NumberList{
protected:
    //Protected Members can't be used outside the class
    struct ListNode{
        char value;
        ListNode *next;
        ListNode(char value1, ListNode *next1 = NULL){
            value = value1;
            next = next1;
        }
    };
    ListNode *head, *tail;  //class members
    //head always points at the 1st letter, tail is used for quick adding at the end
public:
    NumberList() { head = NULL; tail = NULL; }
    ~NumberList(); //don't forget to deallocate space properly at the end
    void displayList() const;  //print out list
    void reverse();
    void add(char newchar) {
        //allocate a new node using the ListNode constructor, by default, next1 will be null
        ListNode *newNode = new ListNode(newchar); //equvalent to ListNode(newchar, NULL);
        if (tail == NULL) { //if no elements in the list, both show to newNode
            tail = newNode;
            head = newNode;
        }else{
            tail->next = newNode; //make last node -> next pointer, point to newNode (new last node)
            tail = tail->next; //make current last node be the actual last node
        }
    }
};
#endif

//------------------------------Main.cpp-----------------------------
#include "Numberlist.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream letterFile("linkedText.txt");
    if (!letterFile){
        cout << "Error in opening the file of letters.";
        exit(-1);
    }

    NumberList numberList;

    char letter;
    while (letterFile >> letter) numberList.add(letter);
}
```

It slightly alters your logic, as you no longer add list nodes to your list,
but I suspect that you don't want to, anyway. Instead, better add the characters
directly to the list, and let the list handle its nodes (makes sense, since the node struct is protected).

Certainly the class needs more refining, but this should solve your initial problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! This really pointed me in the right direction. I created an add method for my class as you outlined above. With a little work I was able to get everything working for the assignment.